# Create a flash object in CQ 5.6.1

Tags: aem, swfobject

I am implementing amcharts in CQ. I get the data by calling a servlet which I temporarily hosted in a local glassfish server. Following is the code snippet of my amchart component jsp.

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%><%@page session="false" %><%
%><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test amcharts generation</title>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="singlesection" class="norm" >
            <div class="norm">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/geometrixx/components/amchart/am/swfobject.js"></script>
                <div id="flashcontent"><strong>You need to upgrade your Flash Player</strong></div>
                <div id="result"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                // <![CDATA[
                    var so = new SWFObject("/apps/geometrixx/components/amchart/am/amstock.swf", "amstock", "600", "400", "8", "#FFFFFF");      
                    var uri = "http://localhost:8080/Charts/apps/CreateXMLFileServlet?r="+Math.random()+"&fc=03";
                    so.addVariable("settings_file", encodeURIComponent(uri));
                    so.addVariable("chart_id", "amstock");
                    so.addVariable("key", "106-d0564444fe0a5ce6839d84f70655375c");
                    so.write("flashcontent");
                // ]]>
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The issue is, the servlet is not getting called. If I try the servlet url directly from the browser, I get the response. Please suggest what I am doing wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: Does any other component that you've created get called successfully? You should look into creating a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — the Flash object may be a red-herring for your debugging. Try to get the component to output 'Hello world' first to track down where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be running into a cross-domain security restriction.  If you are loading the page the has the SWF code from one domain, but then calling a different domain to get the data, you are likely running into security restrictions.  Can you list the full domains for both pieces?

Check out http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html for info on how to get around this.